# Read the buffer data not from file but from a streaming

Tags: c++, fft

how to get the value of *data in the below original function?

I would like to modify it to from get streaming of my computer usb , and I can get the save the stream to file now, I would like to put in fft transform buffer and do the fft transfer.

Here is the original code that I would like to modify the file.read to a streaming input

```
void rawFile2FFT()
{

    // read raw file
    std::ifstream file("output.dat", std::ios::binary);

    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open the RAW file!" << std::endl;
        //return 1;
    }

    uint32_t numSamples=1920018;
    // read file data
    int16_t* data = new int16_t[numSamples];
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), numSamples * sizeof(int16_t));
    file.close();

    // fft transfer
    fftw_complex* in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * numSamples));
    fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(numSamples, in, in, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
        in[i][0] = static_cast<double>(data[i]);
        in[i][1] = 0.0;
    }

    fftw_execute(plan);

    // fft計算結果（頻域資料）samples共1920018，除以2約960008
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < numSamples/2; ++i) {
        double realPart = in[i][0];
        double imagPart = in[i][1];
        double magnitude = sqrt(realPart * realPart + imagPart * imagPart);

        std::cout << "Frequency bin " << i << ": Magnitude=" << magnitude << std::endl;
    }

    // 清理資源
    delete[] data;
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

}
```

Like this one below pRead_data is the streaming data that I got from device,and I would like to do the fft transform.

```
void rawFile2FFT()
{

    while (rxdSize < file_size)
    {
        //get the data
        if (FT4222_SPISlave_GetRxStatus(ftHandle, &rxSize) == FT_OK)
        {
            if (rxSize > 0)
            {
                uint32_t numSamples=1920018;
                timeout = 0;
                uint8* pRead_data = (uint8*)malloc(rxSize);
                // fft transfer
                fftw_complex* in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * numSamples));
                fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(numSamples, in, in, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: What is the question here? Are you facing any errors?

Comment: Read your FFT documentation to see if you can pass it an `std::ostream` object.  Does it have overloaded functions?